# Flutter : TextButtonThemeData not working on TextButton

Tags: flutter

I have created a theme for the app, and somehow the TextButtonTheme does not apply to the TextButton. The rest of the theme works fine for all other areas of the app except for the TextButton. Let me know what went wrong?

Here is my main.dart with app theme

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:testbed/screens/main_screen.dart';

import 'package:testbed/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:testbed/theme/theme.dart';

//void main() => runApp(MyApp());
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool? googleUserLogin = prefs.getBool('loginStatus');
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: googleUserLogin == null ? LoginForm() : MainScreen(),
    theme: AppTheme().themeData,
  ));
}
```

Here is my theme file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Color appBg = Color.fromRGBO(140, 187, 241, 1);
Color whiteShade = Color.fromRGBO(253, 253, 255, 1);
Color pinkShade = Color.fromRGBO(249, 206, 223, 1);
Color blueShade = Color.fromRGBO(215, 221, 233, 1);

class AppTheme {
  ThemeData themeData = ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        backgroundColor: appBg,
        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      backgroundColor: appBg, //Color.fromRGBO(34, 101, 169, 1),
      primaryColor: whiteShade,
      canvasColor: blueShade,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: pinkShade),
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(pinkShade))),
      bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: appBg,
          elevation: 1,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          selectedItemColor: pinkShade,
          unselectedItemColor: whiteShade,
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: pinkShade,
            opacity: 1,
          ),
          unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: whiteShade,
            opacity: 1,
          )));
}
```

Pasted only the relevant widget code. In the theme, I have specified a background color which is not getting applied to the TextButton in this Widget.

```
  Widget buildGridList(List<BookShelf> data) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
      ),
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
        print(data[index].thumbnail);
        return Card(
          shadowColor: Colors.red,
          semanticContainer: true,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: GridTile(
              header: GridTileBar(
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  title: Text(
                    data[index].author,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text("Added on: " + data[index].dateAdded,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _removeBook(data[index].id);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.remove_circle_outline_rounded,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ))),
              child: Image.network(
                data[index].thumbnail,
                height: 60,
                width: 70,
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
              footer: GridTileBar(
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      ),
                      child: Text('Start Reading',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
                      color: IconTheme.of(context).color,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '5',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: const Icon(
                  Icons.bookmark_outline,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              )),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your material app theme section?

Comment: updated with main.dart with app theme

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this today. It seems like `GridTileBar` does not inherit any theme data and forces using `ThemeData.dark()`.

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // omitted for brevity

    final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark();
    return Container(
      padding: padding,
      decoration: decoration,
      height: (title != null && subtitle != null) ? 68.0 : 48.0,
      child: Theme(
        data: darkTheme,
        // child: ...
      ),
    );
  }
```

I may avoid using `GridTileBar` in my app due to this.

References:

- PR that forces using `ThemeData.dark()`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/78574
- Link to source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d3c60569d16c5b11ce1e49ca66fbcd1431f82017/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/grid_tile_bar.dart#L71-L78